# How do I auto scale an axis with a max height in highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

[Example plunk refereed to below](http://plnkr.co/edit/3BvbWh?p=preview).

I have a line chart where the Y axis is a percentage between 0 and 1. Sometimes my highest percentage is less than 1% sometimes its between 99 and 100%. It never makes sense to have more than 100% displayed on the legend.

The problem is if I set `max: 1` and have data that is all below 0.1, the chart looks flat like in the second example. However, If I don't set `max` and the data is approaching 100%, then y axis will render ticks up to 125%.

How do let the legend autoscale, but cap the max value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this in your y-axis:

```
yAxis: {
    max: 1,
    min: 0
}
```

If you instead go for this, it should be more understandable:

```
yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    endOnTick: false
}
```

To clarify, you had `max: 1` and `endOnTick: true` (default), and according to [the API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.max):

> If the `endOnTick` option is true, the `max` value might be rounded up.

See [this updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3HgOLnAezWCiYWNwn1Wr?p=preview) for a demonstration.

The same goes for starting at 0%. You could remove `min` and set `startOnTick: false`.